# Image thumbnails browser resizing quality

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a slider that auto generates thumbnails of big images. The problem is that, while the quality of resized images in Chrome for example is good, in firefox/IE it is terrible. It looks too sharpened and impossible to read the text.

Is there a way to fix this through css/html ? I'm attaching an example to help you understand my issue:

http://i49.tinypic.com/2vba8t0.jpg

Comment: Are the resized images just the large images with a defined width and height?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason why Chrome looks good is because they have it built-in to their application to optimize images in this situation to look better to the user, other browsers do not. So you will want something that properly scales down the images for you and it seems like you currently are manually setting the width and height of the bigger images to make smaller images.  I don't know of a css/html solution that will work for you, unless you manually make thumbnails to the proper size and load them instead of the large ones.  If you don't want to do that you can use a solution like [jQuery NailThumb](http://www.garralab.com/nailthumb.php) that will create them via javascript for you.